# Is a JavaScript class an object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I assume that an ES6 class is an object as "everything" is objects in JavaScript. Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: classes are objects, but not "everything" is an object. Primitives (strings, numbers etc) can be autoboxed to objects, but they are not objects per se.

Comment: "Classes" are just functions and functions are objects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the point of view of `Object Oriented Programming` *class* is **not** an *object*. It is an *abstraction*. And every object of that is a concrete instance of that abstraction.

From the point of view of JavaScript, *class* is an *object*, because *class* is a *ES6* feature and under it simple function is used. It is not just an abstraction in Javascript, but also an object by itself. And that function is an object. It has it's own properties and functions.

So speaking in Javascript not everything is an object. There are also primitive types - `number`, `string`, `boolean`, `undefined`, `symbol` from `ES6`. When you will use some methods with this primitive types except `undefined`, they will be converted into the objects.

You can see the below example.

```js
const str = 'Text';
const strObj = new String('Text');

console.log(str);
console.log(strObj.toString());

console.log(typeof str);
console.log(typeof strObj);
```

There is also one extra primitive type `null`, but checking it's type returns an *object*. This is a bug.

```js
console.log(typeof null);
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct. In most OO languages, classes are objects (cf. `java.lang.Class`), moreover, even a metaclass (a class of classes) is an object of its own.

Comment: Suren is not saying that *classes* in other languages are not objects. He is saying that in the concept of OOP, a *class* is not an object, but a type of object

Comment: @georg I am speaking about OOP globally, not for some languages

Comment: This is the most incomprehensible technically correct answer I can imagine!

Comment: Since the answer explains the primitives, you could also mention symbol primitive for completion sake. And the funniest JS quirk ever, `typeof null === 'object'`.

Comment: I wanted to write about `null`, but didn't. Will edit

Answer (score 8):

ES6 class is a function, and any function is an object:

```
(class {}).constructor === Function
(class {}) instanceof Function === true
(class {}) instanceof Object === true
```

Although not every object is `Object` instance:

```
Object.create(null) instanceof Object === false
```

The statement that everything is an object is not correct. That's an oversimplified way to say that some primitive values in JavaScript can be *coerced* to objects:

```
(1).constructor === Number
1 instanceof Number === false
```

But primitives aren't objects until they are *converted*:

```
Object(1) instanceof Number === true
Object(1) instanceof Object === true
```

And `null` and `undefined` can't be coerced at all:

```
null instanceof Object === false
Object(null) instanceof Object === true // conversion
(null).constructor // coercion error
typeof null === 'object' // JS bug
```

Comment: This is a clean and helpful answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is.

If you do:

```
class Hello { };
```

then `Hello` is in itself an object an can be used like any other:

```
console.log(Hello.toString()); // outputs 'class Hello { }'
```

As you say, *eveything* in JavaScript is an object

In fact:

```
console.log(Hello instanceof Object); // prints 'true'
```

Comment: We're not speaking about OOP or its concepts, but about JavaScript in particular.

Answer (score 2):

The real question is whether Javascript classes are *classes*!

In reality they are not. Javascript's object model is prototype-based, rather than class-based, which makes it hard to understand. The `class` syntax is a useful tool, but it is really only syntactic sugar to make the model easier to understand.

In reality, a JS class is actually a function, with a prototype associated with it.

```
class Hippo{};
Hippo.__proto__ === Function.prototype; // true
```

All JS functions are also objects.

```
Hippo.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype; // true
```

The prettier way to say this is

```
Hippo instanceof Object; // true
```

So a JS class is an object and a function -- but it isn't really a class!

Comment: JS *class* is an *object* and a function -- but it isn't really a *class*. I think Javascript is a bit incomprehensible  )

Comment: @SurenSrapyan Undoubtedly.

Comment: Javascript breaks OOP.

Comment: *"In reality they are not."* So, what makes a class a *class*?

Answer (score 0):

Class is a function in Javascript, Only function has prototype property, not the object.

Check code below

```js
class MyClass {}
MyClass.prototype.value = 'My Class Value'; // Works same as function
const myclass = new MyClass();
console.log(myclass.value);

function MyFunc() {}
MyFunc.prototype.value = 'My Function Value';
const myfunc = new MyFunc();
console.log(myfunc.value);

var MyObject = {};
MyObject.prototype.value = 10; // Throws an error
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question. From the OOP 001, Object is an instance of the class.  So at no point can class be an object again